# formidable not saying file type to end of file uploaded

Tags: node.js, next.js, formidable

the following code, is uploading the file to the directory, however it is not adding the file extension to the created file. Nor is it sending back  `res.status(200).json({status:'success'});`

However I do know that it is uploading them because I can see it in the folder `public\files\f754121781049b2ef8557ef21` you can see they don't assign the extension file type.

```
import formidable from 'formidable';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  //const uploadFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'public','files');


  form.uploadDir = "public/files";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    //console.log(files.campaignAudio.newFilename);
    var file = files[0]

    try{
        const newFile = File.create({
            name:`files\${files.campaignAudio.newFilename}.mp3`
        });
        res.status(200).json({status:'success'});
    }
    catch(error){
        res.send(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.keepExtensions = true;`

is deprecated syntax, instead pass in an object to formidable function with all the options inside.

you are also not catching any errors, before your try catch ...

Use something like

```
 if (err) {
 res
return;
}
```